# How to deal with js templates duplication of server code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, templates

I've noticed that I often duplicate razor code by making javascript templates for ajax loading. And then if I want to change serverside template I have to change js template too, what can I do to minimize such duplication? Thanks for answers, and forgive my english:)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to use the same template engine on the server side and on the client side for the specific purpose of AJAX requests.

[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) is a good choice - it's available both for [.NET platform](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache) and for [JavaScript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Comment: That's good, but I like the razor and don't want to use another server-side template engine. If there are any others solutions, tell about them.